# Persistent Header to Appear Only On Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm using the following David Walsh snippet with jQuery to power a persistent header div#topbar.  But, I am trying to figure out how to have the header only display once the user scrolls at least 100px.

I tried adding a window listener snippet, but it essentially broke the persistent header snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function() {
    var fadeSpeed = 200, fadeTo = 0.5, topDistance = 30;
    var topbarME = function() { $('#topbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,1); }, topbarML = function() { $('#topbar').fadeTo(fadeSpeed,fadeTo); };
    var inside = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        position = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(position > topDistance && !inside) {
            topbarML();
            $('#topbar').bind('mouseenter',topbarME);
            $('#topbar').bind('mouseleave',topbarML);
            inside = true;
        }
        else if (position < topDistance){
            topbarME();
            $('#topbar').unbind('mouseenter',topbarME);
            $('#topbar').unbind('mouseleave',topbarML);
            inside = false;
        }
    });
})();
```

});

**I've found a solution.**

I replaced that snippet with this one:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var startY= $('#header').position().top + $('#header').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
        $('#topbar').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#topbar').slideUp();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: See [Persistent Headers](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't at all address only displaying the header after the user scrolls the window a certain distance.

Comment: Are you sure? See the demo at the end of it

Comment: Yup, that is for fixing an element within the page so that it does not leave the screen when you scroll.  But, it's okay, I found a solution, thanks.  Posting it now.

Comment: You should stick your solution in an Answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var startY= $('#header').position().top + $('#header').outerHeight();
  $(window).scroll(function () {
  if($(this).scrollTop() > startY ){
    $('#topbar').slideDown();
  }else{
    $('#topbar').slideUp();
  }
});
```